# facebook api not returning work,location and email fields

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, social-networking, scribe

I have started using the FacebookAPi using the Scribe library.I generated the access key with the scopes "read_stream,publish_stream,email,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_hometown,user_work_history,user_relationships,user_location,user_interests,user_hometown" and trying to make a people search application with the follwing url

https://graph.facebook.com/search?&fields=id,name,gender,locale,username,third_party_id,education,hometown,picture,email,location,work,link&q=&type=user&access_token=

But it doesnot return me email,location,work fields.

I tried using the FQL but it returns me most of the fields as null.

How should I get these fields even when I got the all the access from the user.

Comment: The Scribe Library uses authroize URL as https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=% s&scope=%s&redirect_uri=%s 
and access URL as https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token

Comment: Their was a couple of posts where has that gone?

Comment: Please update your initial post instead of adding too much comments.

Answer (score 0):

Even though that you might see people's `work`, `location` and `email`, the API doesn't let you access this information unless they are your friends or that you follow them.

This has probably been thought to avoid any automation that would indefinitely grab the public content on Facebook.

Also, permissions only applies to a user (`user_birthdays`, `user_photos`, etc.) and his friends (`friends_events`, `friends_interests`, etc.). That totally means there is **no existing permission** for the others: the users you will find on the "search". No permission = no data.

Comment: I actually donot want the details of the current user and as far as my knowledge goes "/me" is used for getting data of the current user.                                                              I want do a generic name search (for example) which might not be of the current user and it should return me the email,location,work. Is it possible.

Comment: Is there no way we can get these data.Because when we search within the facebook application for some other user from our page we can get all the details like work,location on the users page so logically it should be available to all the apps as the users would have made it public that is why it is shown to me when I am not the friend of the user I am searching for.